# using shortcuts to move in bash command line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, inputrc

When I use <kbd>Ctrl+Left_arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Right_arrow</kbd> in bash, I move backward a "word" and forward a "word" respectively. I belive, this is defined in `/etc/inputrc`

```
# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

Unfortunately, the definition of "word" here is misleading. It considers `/foo/bar` as two words.

Is it possible to modify this so that the only word delimiter is space character ?
(one or more spaces, or one or more tabs)

i.e. `/foo/bar/` should be treated as one word

I am using Debian Wheezy

Comment: Space is also a delimiter.

Comment: @taliezin - I meant only space character and nothing else. I have modified my question to make it clear.

Comment: Sorry I did not get it.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is not delimiter but in words symbols which can be alphabet symbols, digit or underline only so any which is not from list count as delimiter.